# error with creating backup of Godaddy DB on Local Machine

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, backup

I am in need of restoring My Updated Database on GoDaddy.

I had old database backup(ypldb.bak) from Godaddy. The backup(ypldb.bak) had been created from Godaddy hosting account.

I had to do some update on this database backup file.
So I restored this backup file on my Local Machine [SqlServer 2005]. And done the Update.

Now I want to create backup of this updated database which is on my local machine, so that i can restore newly created backup file on go daddy hosting account.

but during the creation of backup on local machine it giving error.
The error is–

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express
------------------------------

Backup failed for Server 'ARCHANA-PC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Backup+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Failed to pause catalog for backup. Backup was aborted. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.2047.00&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I tried to find solution from following link but didn't find any useful solution
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlkjmanageability/thread/77f9921d-338d-49f0-addb-5e11178f4ab9/

suggest me some useful solution so I can try to take database backup as soon as possible